# Вебхук на c# для телеграм бота

Tags: c#, webhook

Пытаюсь создать бота, который при появлении на сайте новости, стучал мне в телеграмм. Использую C# и tg api. Не совсем понимаю с чего начать. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тебе сначала нужен веб-сервис который будет принимать эти веб-хуки, если ты играешься с простым консольным приложением, то не советую тебе делать веб хуки, просто тыкай через long polling, своего бота. А если намеришься создавать свой веб-сервис для веб хуков, то вот хороший пример https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot.Examples/tree/master/Telegram.Bot.Examples.WebHook. Так-же для того чтобы телеграм апи отправлял тебе запросы о новых событиях, тебе нужно иметь https протокол, его можно получить задеплоив сервис на azure, или (более легкий вариант) использовать ngrok, как пользоваться написано в репозитории что выше